# publish failed build successful vs2008

Tags: asp.net

------ Build started: Project: CUOnlineManager, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
CUOnlineManager -> E:\Vault\CUOnlineManager3\CUOnlineManager\bin\CUOnlineManager.dll
------ Publish started: Project: CUOnlineManager, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Connecting to E:\E\55...
Publishing folder /...
Publishing folder App_Data...
Publishing folder BusCards...
Publishing folder BusCards/Images...
Publishing folder Clearance...
Publishing folder Controls...
Publishing folder CoordinationOffice...
Publishing folder Coordinator...
Publishing folder culogin...
Publishing folder DarkReports...
Publishing folder DateSheet...
Publishing folder DirectorConsole...
Publishing folder DirectorConsole/COMSIS...
Publishing folder DirectorConsole/CUPortal...
Publishing folder DirectorConsole/FacultyFolder...
Publishing folder DirectorConsole/Library...
Publishing folder DirectorConsole/StudentFee...
Publishing folder Faculty...
Publishing folder Faculty/Portal...
Publishing folder FacultyManagement...
Publishing folder FeedBack...
Publishing folder FeedBack/CSS...
Publishing folder FeedBack/FacultyRepeaterReports...
Publishing folder FeedBack/images...
Publishing folder FeedBack/Reports...
Publishing folder FeedBack/Scripts...
Publishing folder HOD...
Publishing folder HOD/Attendance...
Publishing folder HOD/EmployeeAttendance...
Publishing folder HOD/FacultyFolder...
Publishing folder HOD/Offices...
Publishing folder HOD/Reports...
Publishing folder HOD/Students...
Publishing folder HR...
Publishing folder images...
Publishing folder Library...
Publishing folder obj...
Publishing folder obj/Debug...
Publishing folder obj/Debug/Refactor...
Publishing folder obj/Debug/TempPE...
Publishing folder obj/Release...
Unable to add 'obj/Release/CUOnlineManager.dll' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'obj\Release\CUOnlineManager.dll'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'obj/Release/CUOnlineManager.pdb' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'obj\Release\CUOnlineManager.pdb'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Publishing folder Officers...
Publishing folder resources...
Publishing folder resources/css...
Publishing folder resources/images...
Publishing folder resources/images/icons...
Publishing folder resources/img...
Publishing folder resources/jqueryUI...
Publishing folder resources/jqueryUI/base...
Publishing folder resources/jqueryUI/base/images...
Publishing folder resources/jqueryUI/redmond...
Publishing folder resources/jqueryUI/redmond/images...
Publishing folder resources/jqueryUI/themes...
Publishing folder resources/jqueryUI/themes/base...
Publishing folder resources/jqueryUI/themes/base/images...
Publishing folder resources/jqueryUI/themes/redmond...
Publishing folder resources/jqueryUI/themes/redmond/images...
Publishing folder resources/jqueryUI/ui...
Publishing folder resources/jqueryUI/ui/design...
Publishing folder resources/jqueryUI/ui/i18n...
Publishing folder resources/jqueryUI/ui/minified...
Publishing folder resources/scripts...
Publishing folder resources/timepicker...
Publishing folder resources/timepicker/include...
Publishing folder resources/timepicker/include/ui-1.10.0...
Publishing folder resources/timepicker/include/ui-1.10.0/ui-lightness...
Publishing folder resources/timepicker/include/ui-1.10.0/ui-lightness/images...
Publishing folder SMS...
Publishing folder StudentAffairs...
Publishing folder StudentManagement...
Publishing folder theme...
Publishing folder theme/resources...
Publishing folder theme/resources/css...
Publishing folder theme/resources/images...
Publishing folder theme/resources/images/icons...
Publishing folder theme/resources/scripts...
Publishing folder theme/resources/scripts/lib...
Publishing folder theme/resources/scripts/tests...
Publishing folder theme/resources/scripts/tests/functional...
Publishing folder theme/resources/scripts/tests/unit...
Publishing folder TimeTable...
Publishing folder bin...
Publishing folder bin/bin...
Publishing folder bin/obj...
Publishing folder bin/obj/Debug...
Publishing folder bin/_sgbak...
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Please see [help]. You should at least properly **format your question** (also removing unnecessary _noise_), **describe what is not working** (even when it's obvious) and **what you tried** to solve it (so we won't repeat). If you just dump error messages you probably won't get any help.

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple projects in your solution, try rebuilding each one separately 1st then build your main project and publish.

Sometime I would notice behaviour like this in 2008, ALSO make sure your building in debug mode for pdb files to be created.

separately, try upgrading the solution as soon as you can to VS2012/13

Comment: output window showed the missing dll in log,                                                       Unable to add 'obj/Release/CUOnlineManager.pdb' to the Web site. Unable to add file 'obj\Release\CUOnlineManager.pdb'. The system cannot find the file specified.                                                                                                                      and dll file also added,   added file here solved the problem. before that i restarted the system, and directly publish the site.